# Supporting Canvas "Download as Image" in IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html2canvas

I am working on supporting Canvas "Download as Image" in IE or Edge. It seems `canvas.toDataURL()` does not work in IE or edge.

People use `canvas.msToBlob()` for supporting Canvas "Download as Image" in IE or Edge. 
I searched for documentation on `canvas.msToBlob()` method. But what I found is mainly `canvas.toBlob`.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between `msToBlob` and `toBlob`?
2. I found description of `msToBlob` only Microsoft MSDN. So, `msToBlob` has something to do with Microsoft? I hope "ms" in `msToBlob` does not mean Microsoft :)
3. Is it safe to use functions like `msToBlob`/`msSaveBlob` as they do not seem to be global/general/available on all platforms?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does "right click on the canvas, then pick save as" not work? And also, no, anything starting with `ms` is horrendously proprietary and a great idea to avoid. [toDataURL](https://caniuse.com/#search=toDataURL) is most certainly supported by both IE and Edge. However, it will NOT work if you draw "not your own content" on it, so: can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I am basically downloading a Div as image. The contents of that div is dynamically written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The difference between `msToBlob` and `toBlob` is just the usage scenario. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Browser_compatibility), we can see that `toBlob` is not supported by IE and Edge. We need to add the vendor prefix `ms` when use in IE and Edge. Besides, we can specify the image type in `toBlob`, but `msToBlob` returns only PNG.
2. Yes, your guess is right, `ms` is the vendor prefix. Sometimes we need to add the `ms` prefix to make some methods compatible with IE and Edge.
3. There's no documentation indicates that methods with `ms` prefix is unsafe. It's just for the browser compatibility.

Comment: This says, msSaveBlob is obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob